# Appending characters onto string

Tags: java, file, text, input, char

I am trying to write code to import all characters (including spaces) of a given text file into a single string for analysis. I am using the given files in Java for this, and ran across a strange error while putthing it together. I'm not really familiar with coding at all, and would appreciate clarification. What happens is that in the below code, when I set

text.append(ch);

I have errors of Default constructor cannot handle exception thrown by X, must define explicit constructor;

and when I set text.append('ch');

the above errors go away and my 'ch' line just gives invalid char const. error, fixable by removing the ''s.

So I take it I have to construct an explicit constructor for my givens from Java, is this necessary? As I have no idea how to do so, it would be nice to have a roundabout solution.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class TextReader //cannot place inputs/outputs of string on this line
{

StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
//StringBuilder google
//google end of file check java

InputStream in = new FileInputStream("charfile.txt");
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, "US-ASCII");
int intch;
{
while ((intch = r.read()) != -1)
{
    char ch = (char) intch;
        // ...
    text.append(ch); //if I make this a 'ch', the errors above go away, what's the problem?
}
}

}
```

Comment: What? If you have 'ch' it shouldn't make the errors go away. Can you explain better?

Comment: well if I make it 'ch' I think java focuses on the more apparent error.
Literally the only error in the code when ch is 'ch' is the error for 'ch' not being a valid constant char

Comment: When I have ch as just ch, the lines of
'InputStream in'  'Reader r'   'while(('

all give default constructor can't handel exception from X, please explicitly construct

Comment: 'ch' should make a compilation error, since single quotes (mostly) carry one letter only. What is the IDE you are using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your statements in a code block, e.g. `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    // StringBuilder google
    // google end of file check java

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("charfile.txt");
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, "US-ASCII");
    int intch;
    {
        while ((intch = r.read()) != -1) {
            char ch = (char) intch;
            // ...
            text.append(ch); 
        }
    }
}
```

The statements

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("charfile.txt");
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, "US-ASCII");
```

both throw checked exceptions which cannot occur in the class block.

Comment: Uh I guess I overlooked that.
Would this still be true if I only meant to use this as a method to call from another main method in another file that's overlooking the whole project?

Comment: Not sure I get your question but any declarations that will throw exceptions or non-declarative statements should appear in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually IO in java require try and catch block, else it will give you error. Also in above code you have to place the declaration in explicitly define constructor

```
TextReader()
{
//----------- Your Code here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `text.append(ch);`, error should not come at this line. It may complain about other issue e.g. Expected Exceptions not handled or thrown e.g.

**Handled:**

```
    try{
    while ((intch = r.read()) != -1){
        char ch = (char) intch;
            // ...
        text.append(ch);
    }
       }catch(IOException ioex){
          ioex.printStackTace();
       }
```

**Thrown:**

Change your method declaration with `throws` clause as :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
```

When you say `text.append('ch');`, your argument is not a variable or single character literal any more. **You should be getting compilation error at that line.** Though you can do something like `text.append('c');` as `c` is a single character.